# How do i make Internet Explorer portable?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, networking, internet-explorer

As you know support for Internet Explorer (IE) is dropped, but I'm still using it for compatibility purposes. Eg. Bypass Webp format and save images in pure jpg or png format.

I still have my windows 7 partition which I can extract the IE executables but am looking at ways to make IE 6-11 portable so I can simply launch it on my Wi dows 10/11 Desktop as needed. Of course for the bulk of my browsing will be on the latest browser due to stability  and security issues.

So I assume it would be possible to run IE as a standalone exe on Windows 10/11 as there is forward compatibility rather than backward compatibility.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea. Internet Explorer is end of life and you will end up browsing with multiple unpatched security holes. Edge has an IE mode. Alternatively, perhaps you can download the content you need if you change the User-agent string for your browser

Comment: You can bypass webp in other ways, or you can convert webp to jpg or whatever

Comment: you should not use win7 and you should not use IE https://preview.redd.it/is-there-a-way-to-convert-multiple-webp-images-to-jpg-v0-wujfww74mzfa1.png?width=323&format=png&auto=webp&s=d31d66d56808e0622a69da6f3def0ad4acf7a7b1 you can batch convert webp to jpg with Irfanview

Comment: Even if IE is not available, you still have mshtml on your machine for running HTAs.  This is equivalent to running IE9.

Comment: **Simply having Internet Explorer installed/accessible compromises the machine it's on** - it never even has to be run to compromise the machine. When Microsoft became aware of this ~2017ish they actively told everyone to stop using IE because there is no fixing this specific vulnerability that is exploitable, and was being actively exploited IIRC, as they were no longer patching IE. There is no security patch for this vulnerability, there is no way to mitigate it because it deals with a specific extension that cannot be unassigned from IE - the only thing that can be done is to uninstall IE.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5PyNyicx6Cw) showing how. Simply create a VBScript with the following code.

```
CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application").Visible=true
```

This launches the IE pre-installed on Windows 10/11. It's bundled with Windows but can't be launched directly by clicking its executable. No need to port.

Comment: Why risk compromising the entire machine by enabling IE instead of simply using a product made for this very scenario, IE Tab? Has it been verified whether enabling IE through a VBS script creates the same exploitable file extension association that prompted Microsoft and one of its executives to tell _everyone_ within an official Microsoft blog to stop using IE because of this exploit and to uninstall it because this would not be patched? Until that's been verified, this answer is really, really bad advice because of the very real risk IE poses due to an unassignable file association.

Answer (score 0):

This request was already presented
[Portable Apps Internet Explorer](https://portableapps.com/node/23615).

The answer there was that no one can legally package IE as a
portable app, and it also cannot be done due to its tight
integration into Windows, besides the fact that this would
require illegal reverse-engineering.

Nevertheless, and for what it's worth, the site oldversion.com contain
[IE versions](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/internet-explorer/)
from 1.0 to 10. I downloaded and launched the version 10 `.exe`
and it started an installation that I didn't follow through.

Comment: **Simply having Internet Explorer installed/accessible compromises the machine it's on** - it never even has to be run to compromise the machine. When Microsoft became aware of this ~2017ish they actively told everyone to stop using IE because there is no fixing this specific vulnerability that is exploitable, and was being actively exploited IIRC, as they were no longer patching IE. There is no security patch for this vulnerability, there is no way to mitigate it because it deals with a specific extension that cannot be unassigned from IE - the only thing that can be done is to uninstall IE.

Comment: @JW0914: You don't like IE (and you're not alone), but is this a reason to downvote? How do you know that it's not intended for a VM? There are reasons for using IE with all sort of ancient apps, not necessary for everyday surfing. For example, I recently helped someone ask for a visa for entering India, where I needed to do the request using IE, as Edge mode IE didn't work well enough. Luckily I had one lying around.

Comment: I [didn't](https://imgur.com/a/V4jR0S3) downvote your answer. [IE Tab](https://www.ietab.net/) should work in all instances where IE was required. This has nothing to do with a like/dislike of IE - simply having IE installed on a machine, virtual or otherwise, compromises the machine due to an actively exploited file association _(for `.mht` IIRC)_ that cannot be modified from being assigned to IE when IE is installed. A Microsoft executive even wrote a blog about this exact thing in ~2017ish or ~2019ish telling everyone it would not be patched and to stop using IE because of it.

Comment: @JW0914: Excuse me for my hasty assumption, as your comment came at the same time as the downvote.

Comment: It's a fair assumption, as I'll always comment if I downvote